# Cannot Set Variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a variable in bash:

```
b=$(p | cut -d',' -f4)
echo $b
```

However, I keep ending up with:

```
p: command not found
```

I've tried every combination of brackets, curly brackets, and dollar signs but still can't get `b` to equal `$p | cut -d',' -f4`. To my understanding, the dollar signs will extract the value from the variable and the brackets are for expression containment. Is there fundamental bash syntax that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What is `p`? and what exactly are you even trying to do?

Comment: p is a variable that I've obtained through a for loop.

Comment: Well `p` isn't a command, so why try and run it in a subshell like one? I think you'll want an `echo` in front of it, for example: `b=$(echo "$p" | ... )`...

Comment: Try `b=$(echo "$p" | cut -d',' -f4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a here-string to expand the variable value to `p` to `cut` instead of using a pipe-line(`|`) which forks a new sub-shell (avoiding a new process overhead). The `<<<` is `bash` specific and not available in the `POSIX` shell `sh`.

```
b=$(cut -d',' -f4 <<<"$p")
echo "$b"
```

Also double-quote your variables to avoid word-splitting by shell.

Answer (score 1):

The code below would also work, and would probably be higher performance by avoiding a call to the external program `cut` and using only the `read` builtin :

```
IFS="," read -r dummy dummy dummy b dummy  <<<"$p"
echo "$b"
```

You could also collect all values in an array, and reference them afterwards

```
IFS="," read -r -a array <<<"$p"
echo "${array[4]}"              # Print 4th field
echo "${#array[@]}"             # Print field count
```

In all cases, `IFS=","` is how you tell `read` to use commas as field separators, and `-r` forces backslashes to be used as is, not interpreted (e.g. `\n` will not be seen as a newline, but rather just as a literal two-character string).

Please note that the examples above only handle strings that do not contain newlines.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Bash patterns for this?

- With parameter expansions (super portable):

  ```
  b=${p#*,*,*,}
  b=${b%%,*}
  ```
- By splitting the comma-separated string and reading only the fourth field (Bash only):

  ```
  IFS=, read -r -d '' _ _ _ b _ < <(printf '%s,\0' "$p")
  ```
- By using a regex (that will also provide some sort of validation, Bash only):

  ```
  if [[ $p =~ ^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*).*$ ]]; then
      b=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  else
      echo >&2 "String doesn't match"
  fi
  ```
- By fully splitting the string into an array (same as point 2 above, Bash only):

  ```
  IFS=, read -r -d '' -a pary < <(printf '%s,\0' "$p")
  b=${pary[3]}
  ```

Comment: You use zero-delimited string to feed into read.  Is that to allow newlines inside the field values?  You may want to explain the reason, as I am sure it is useful.  Maybe it can be avoided sometimes, for instance if `p` contains individual lines from a file that were read using newlines as line separators.  The parameter expansion I did not think of, certainly the fastest and most concise solution in this case.

Comment: @Fred: I'm not using a null-delimited string. I'm using `read` with a null delimiter `-d ''` and the `\0` in the `printf` format is only to have `read` return `0` (success); without `\0`, `read` would return `1`. The construct I'm using allows newlines in the string. It's the only robust way I know of to split a string on delimiters (apart from parsing it with a loop).

Comment: Would it be valid to say that if the string can be assumed to contain no newlines, then `-d ''` can be dropped and `<<<"$p"` used instead of the `printf` process substitution?

Comment: About the null-delimited string...  Wouldn't `printf "%s\0"` produce a string terminated by a null byte?

Comment: @Fred: if you're sure that `p` doesn't contain newlines characters (or, if it does, you only want to split the first line), then it's fine to use `<<< "$p"` (and it's much faster too). Regarding the format `%s,\0`, the comma is here to allow empty trailing fields. Compare `p=hello,word, IFS=, read -r -d '' -a ary < <(printf '%s\0' "$p"); declare -p ary` and `p=hello,word, IFS=, read -r -d '' -a ary < <(printf '%s,\0' "$p"); declare -p ary`.

Answer (score 0):

If p is a variable then try this:

```
b=$(echo "$p" | cut -d',' -f4)
echo $b
```